# SQL Dynamic Stock Movement Report

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-view

I have managed to get data from a database that looks as follows:

```
STOCKNAME | STORENAME | WEEKNUM  | SOH   | SALES
Apples    | Store 1   | 10       |   1   |  3
Apples    | Store 1   |  9       |   4   |  1
Apples    | Store 1   |  8       |   5   |  
Pears     | Store 1   | 10       |  15   |  0
Pears     | Store 1   |  9       |  15   |  0
Pears     | Store 1   |  8       |  15   |  
Mangoes   | Store 1   | 10       |  33   | 15 <-- They could have received more stock between week week
Mangoes   | Store 1   |  9       |  25   |  8
Mangoes   | Store 1   |  8       |  32   |
```

The Weeknumber changes, depending on when the next set of information is imported eg. The next week will be week 11 and each store will send through their Stock On Hand (SOH). Weeks will then change to 11, 10, 9.

I was wondering if there was an easy method in calculating the differences between the weeks without first calculating the difference between the 10th and 9th week **(CALC A)**. and then calculating the difference between the 9th and 8th week. and then calculating the difference between those **(CALC B)**. And then calculating the difference between **(CALC A) - (CALC B)**

**EXPECTED RESULTS**

```
STOCKNAME        | STORENAME      | SALES  | SOH
Apples           | Store 1        |  4     |  1
Pears            | Store 1        |  0     | 15   **<--- Alert Stock Not Selling. Attention Require!!**
Mangoes          | Store 1        | 23     | 33
```

The purpose of the report is to ensure that there is movement in the stock within the last 3 weeks.

So Apples there has been movement. 
Pears there is a problem.

- This would indicate that the pears are sitting somewhere where a customer cannot see them,
- the product may be defective,
- the salesperson is not pushing the sales of the pears.
- many other reasons

This is my train of thought so far:

I think this may be an answer. Probably not the best.

1. Add the Sales / SUM From Data without the weeknumber. This should show if there has been any unit sales for the last three weeks. Add an additional static column with alias called **TransactionType** with the value 'Sales Last 3 Weeks'

   ```
   SELECT STOCKNAME, STORENAME, 0 AS SOH, SUM(SALES) AS QTY, 'Sales Last 3 Weeks' AS TRANSACTIONTYPE 
   FROM TABLE1
   GROUP BY STOCKNAME, STORENAME,'Sales Last 3 Weeks' AS TRANSACTIONTYPE
   ```
2. Run another query on the data and bring through the MAX Weeknumber SOH figure. Add an additional static column with alias called **TransactionType** with the value 'Current SOH'

   ```
   SELECT STOCKNAME, STORENAME, SOH, 0 AS QTY, 'SOH' AS TRANSACTIONTYPE 
   FROM TABLE1
   GROUP BY STOCKNAME, STORENAME,'SOH' AS TRANSACTIONTYPE
   HAVING WEEKNUMBER = 10        <-- Not sure how to dynamic this. Weeknumber will change
   ```
3. UNION the Queries 1 and 2 above.

   ```
   SELECT * FROM QUERY1
   UNION
   SELECT * FROM QUERY2
   ```
4. Then search those results for

   ```
   CASE WHEN (QTY = 0 and SOH > 0) THEN 'Attention Required Here' ELSE 'Everything is Cool' END
   ```

Comment: Can you add expected result (according to you sample data)? Also, tag dbms product used - the answer may depend on it.

Comment: Look into window functions and LAG() in particular. Using windows functions you should be able to do the calculations in one statement.